# Remove all empty nodes from XML with Groovy

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xml-parsing, removechild

I want to remove all empty nodes by using groovy

This is xml and I want to remove telephone and team

```
<Profile>
    <Name>Fin</Name>
    <Aga>20</Aga>
    <Contact>
        <Mobile>1819</Mobile>
        <Telephone/>
    </Contact>
    <Team>
        <Team1/>
        <Team2/>
    </Team>
</Profile>
```

This is my code.

```
  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
  import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
  import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
  import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
  import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
  import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
  import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

   import org.w3c.dom.Document;
   import org.w3c.dom.Node;


   import groovy.xml.*

boolean cleanNode( def node ) {
    node.value().with { a ->
        a.findAll { !it.value }.each { a.remove( it.key ) }
    }
    node.children().with { kids ->
        kids.findAll { it instanceof Node ? !cleanNode( it ) : false }
            .each { kids.remove( it ) }
    }
    node.attributes() || node.children() || node.text()
}




static main(args) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xmlDoc = parser.parse("C:/Users/Myuser/Desktop/Testxml2.xml");//file has the xml*/
    String xml = nodeToString(xmlDoc.getDocumentElement());
    def root = new XmlParser().parseText( xml );
    cleanNode(root)
    def test = XmlUtil.serialize(root);
    println test;
}

static String nodeToString(Node node) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
      Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
      t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
      t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
      t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
    } catch (TransformerException te) {
      System.out.println("nodeToString Transformer Exception");
    }
    return sw.toString();
}
```

But This is not working because Telephone and Team are not deleted

This is output

```
<Profile>
        <Name>Fin</Name>
        <Aga>20</Aga>
        <Contact>
            <Mobile>1819</Mobile>
            <Telephone/>
        </Contact>
        <Team>
            <Team1/>
            <Team2/>
        </Team>
  </Profile>
```

This is Expected Result

```
<Profile>
    <Name>Fin</Name>
    <Aga>20</Aga>
    <Contact>
        <Mobile>1819</Mobile>
    </Contact>
</Profile>
```

Could your please tell me about this?

Comment: Bell Aimsaard, Please check the solution and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as mentioned below:

- find all node names where node text is empty
- loop thru the above find result, and remove node

```groovy
def xmlString = """<Profile>
    <Name>Fin</Name>
    <Aga>20</Aga>
    <Contact>
        <Mobile>1819</Mobile>
        <Telephone/>
    </Contact>
    <Team>
        <Team1/>
        <Team2/>
    </Team>
</Profile>"""

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlString)
def nodes = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() && !it.text()}
def removeNode = { node ->
   def parent = node.parent()
   parent.remove(node)
}

nodes.each{removeNode(it)}
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

You can also quickly try the same on-line <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/nJFj20)</kbd>

Comment: Just a request @rao, It would be great if you can paste the output of your code in the answer itself.It saves time as we need not to goto demo page. Demo page is really helpful though when we want to edit code

Comment: Thanks for the input. If you see the question, OP has already mentioned desired output. But the reason for demo link is to try for himself and see if it is working and also as you rightly pointed that one can modify certain things and retry without hassle and do it quickly.

Comment: Yes its there, but a person answering the question may overlook certain things like you remember in my last question there was one extra line coming in the output xml in the posted answer which was not there in original Question. So its better to copy paste the exact output in my opinion